# SoundEffect from XNA keeps looping even when the if condition explicitly forbids it to

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

```
private void updateDisplay(Object displayBlock)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = timeWatch.Elapsed;

        if (stopRing == true)
        {
            stopRing = true;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            stopRing = false;
        }

        if (ts.Minutes == 0 && ts.Seconds == 10 && ts.Milliseconds <= 100 && stopRing == false)
        {
            stopRing = true;
            btnSound_Click_1(null, null);
        }

        TextBlock db = (TextBlock)displayBlock;
        db.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate() { db.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds); });


    }
```

EDIT: The reason for the if(stopRing == true) is because in the future, I'd like to add more conditions to the function below so that it will ring again after a certain period of time, for example:

```
if (ts.Minutes == 0 && ts.Seconds == 10 && ts.Milliseconds <= 100 && stopRing == false || ts.Minutes == 0 && ts.Seconds == 20 && ts.Milliseconds <= 100 && stopRing == false)
```

but to make things simpler during debugging, I only made the if condition so that it rings only once when ts.Seconds = 10. When I press the reset button, and ts.Seconds goes from 0 to 10 again, it should ring only once, but at this moment it rings multiple times, unpredictably.

and my code for the sound effect is:

```
private void btnSound_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("sounds/Ding.wav");
       SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
       FrameworkDispatcher.Update();

       effect.Play();
    }
```

the update display function is called by:

```
timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(updateDisplay), textblockTimer, 0, 100);
```

What happens is that if I switch the TimerCallBack period to a lower value (such as 100 seen here), the SoundEffect will be played multiple times, very quickly. If I increase the TimerCallBack to a higher value such as 500, the SoundEffect will be played 2-3 times, sometimes quickly sometimes with about 200ms of delay in between.

I'm running out of ideas here... I don't know how can the sound be played when I specify the boolean value to be true, thereby blocking it from executing.
Any help will be much appreciated.

(stopRing is defined on top of the code)

EDIT: few more things to add: the first time round, the SoundEffect usually plays well (only a single time). But if I press the reset button and try again, most of the time the SoundEffect plays multiple times, some times it is okay.

Here is my code for the reset button:

```
    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        timeWatch.Stop();
        timeWatch.Reset();
        paused = true;
        btnStartStop.Content = "Start";
        textblockTimer.Text = "00:00";
    }
```

and my Start/Stop button:

```
private void btnStartStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (paused == true)
        {
            timeWatch.Start();
            timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(updateDisplay), textblockTimer, 0, 100);
            paused = false;
            btnStartStop.Content = "Pause";
        }
        else
        {
            timeWatch.Stop();
            paused = true;
            btnStartStop.Content = "Start";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ill see what I can do to help you. But in general if you can avoid the Thread.Sleep do it..  What is the reason for your first if? If the sound already is playing, why not just let the function return? How long is your sound? And whats the intention behind the code? Ding when you click a button? And not ding again if its already dinging?

Comment: Try posting this on [CodeReview.se]

Comment: Why are you using a timer when there's this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.islooped.aspx

Comment: Evelie: I can sort of see the problem here.
My objective is: 
if (ts.Minutes ==0 && ts.Seconds == 10)
{
buttonSound_Click_1(null, null);
*stop the if function from executing for at least 1 seconds (in fact, it doesn't need to execute for at least 50 seconds*
}
The only reason I used the stopRing boolean is to try to stop the if function from executing.

Answer (score 0):

A few things just scream "logic error" in your code:

- The 2nd `if` in `updateDisplay` checks the value of `stopRing`, but `stopRing` will always be false at that point (if it was true when the method was called, the previous block of code set it to false)
- You set the `updateDisplay` function to be called every 100ms, but it contains a `Thread.Sleep` of 1000ms.

At this point I'm not sure what exactly is causing the behavior you're seeing, but this should give you some avenues to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, I need to call the timer.Dispose() method when I press the reset button to recalibrate the timer, so that previous instance of the timer doesn't interfere with the new one.

Solved!

So what does this mean?
This means that I don't have to use the stopRing boolean anymore (not that it helps), resulting in a much cleaner code.

Thank you all for helping!